# Not showing messages at onestepcheckout in magento 2.2.x

Tags: magento2.2, knockoutjs

After the ajax process get the error from the payment api i can see that the `Magento_Ui/js/model/messages.js` it triggered and the **message should be added to the list** but I cant see anything in the front end.

I can see also that the content of the message it is at `type.push(messageObj.message);`

```
        /**
     * Add  message to list.
     * @param {Object} messageObj
     * @param {Object} type
     * @returns {Boolean}
     */
    add: function (messageObj, type) {
        var expr = /([%])\w+/g,
            message;

        if (!messageObj.hasOwnProperty('parameters')) {
            this.clear();
            type.push(messageObj.message);

            return true;
        }
        message = messageObj.message.replace(expr, function (varName) {
            varName = varName.substr(1);

            if (messageObj.parameters.hasOwnProperty(varName)) {
                return messageObj.parameters[varName];
            }

            return messageObj.parameters.shift();
        });
        this.clear();
        this.errorMessages.push(message);

        return true;
    },
```

I tried with the blank template but still the same issue

----------------- UPDATE --------------------

The messages work fine if it if there is a product with shipment and the actual message shows in the payment method area as they should but in the case of virtual products with out shipping that that it is my need they stop showing.

Comment: Magento does not provide any onestepcheckout ferature.Do you have  using any 3rd party module?

Comment: yes i do but they claim to be working at there end it is my 4th day trying to get this error message working i tried to take all my code away but still no luck

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using a module for the onestepcheckout it's hard to say what the issue is here. Normally my first advice is to contact the developer of the extension to solve the issue with them. But before you contact them there's a few things that you can test:

1. Are error messages showing in the rest of the website?
2. Are error messages working when you use the default Magento 2 checkout?

If these answers are "yes" then it's more likely a problem with the extension that you're using. If no errors are showing anywhere, then it's a completely different issue.

Messages in the default Magento 2 theme are added in `default.xml` of the Magento/Theme module. The `page.messages` container is by default added to the `columns.top` container.

You could check the extension layout files to make sure that they don't remove or move these container. (Does the `.messages` div exist in your onecheckcheckout page?)

If it's missing you could try re-adding the block yourself:

```
<referenceContainer name="columns.top">               
    <container name="page.messages" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="page messages">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="ajax.message.placeholder" template="Magento_Theme::html/messages.phtml"/>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages" name="messages" as="messages" template="Magento_Theme::messages.phtml"/>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: It dosn't wok adding this code and the messages are showing with non virtual products with the shipping container (I edited my question)

Comment: Hmm, that's something completely different from what I understood from your question. One of the questions still applies though, do the messages work with the default Magento 2 checkout?

Comment: @sduif i tried in my custom checkout module layout/checkout_index_index.xml but even it's not displaying any error messages

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the end of the `checkout_index_index.xml` file in the `Magento_Checkout` module, you will see the `page.messages` container is removed there. I have a hunch it is removed for a specific purpose, but if you want to bring it back, you can place a new `checkout_index_index.xml` file in a `layout` folder in your theme (like `app/design/frontend/MyAwesomeTheme/default/Magento_Checkout/layout/`) with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.messages" remove="false" />
    </body>
</page>
```

The `false` will cancel out the removal.

You can also place the file in a module folder, but then you must make sure to let your module sequence after `Magento_Checkout` in your `module.xml`. Like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="AwesomeVendor_AwesomeModule" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```